# IMSCP + application errors

Tags: php, apache

i have IMSCP and Laravel 5/ Prestashop, if i want show any error page (404) i see the default Apache2 error page.

Apache error log:
[Sat Jan 02 00:07:57.459343 2016] [core:info] [pid 6290:tid 140116177704704] [client 83.240.80.243:62174] AH00128: File does not exist: /var/www/virtual/webpage.cz/htdocs/errors/404.html

Apache config:

`
    ServerAdmin webmaster@webpage.cz
    ServerName webpage.cz
    ServerAlias www.webpage.cz

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/virtual/webpage.cz/htdocs

LogLevel debug
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/webpage.cz/error.log
```

### Alias /errors /var/www/virtual/webpage.cz/htdocs/index.php

```
<FilesMatch "\.php5?$">
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php5-fpm-webpage.cz.socket|fcgi://webpage.cz"
</FilesMatch>

<Directory /var/www/virtual/webpage.cz>
    Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/virtual/webpage.cz/htdocs>
    AllowOverride All
 </Directory>


ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /stats http://localhost/stats/webpage.cz
ProxyPassReverse /stats http://localhost/stats/webpage.cz

<Location /stats>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^(.+)?config=([^?&]+)(.*) $1?config=webpage.cz&$3 [NC,L]
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Statistics for domain webpage.cz"
    AuthUserFile /var/www/virtual/webpage.cz/.htpasswd
    AuthGroupFile /var/www/virtual/webpage.cz/.htgroup
    Require group statistics
</Location>

Include /etc/apache2/imscp/webpage.cz.conf
```

`

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin for i-mscp for a custom default server page
http://i-mscp.net/filebase/index.php/File/28-ServerDefaultPage/